# How to set min and max attributes for input type week

Tags: html, attributes, max, min

I dont want users to select weeks below and above a specific date. I can't seem to figure out how it works. I know about the attributes `min` and `max`, and know how to use them for a date picker. But not for a week picker. I have tried the following:

```html
<input type="week" min="01-01-2021" max="31-12-2021">
<input type="week" min="01-2021" max="52-2021">
<input type="week" min="2021-01" max="2021-05">
// Etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/week#validation) it says we should use this:

```html
<input type="week" min="2021-W01" max="2021-W52">
```

And it works :)